# How to select a substring surrounded by delimiters in DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, substring, delimiter

I would like to select the substring between '/' delimiters.
This is my sample data:

```
1/1/1990
13/111/1990
131/1/1990
2/11/1990
```

I want to get this output:

```
1   1    1990
13  111  1990
131 1    1990
2   11   1990
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT date,SUBSTRING(date, LOCATE('/', date)+ 1, LOCATE('/', date)-1) FROM data
```

Unfortunately, when the date is 13/1/1990 or 1/13/1990, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DB2 supports [`regexp_substr()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html):

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^/\+]+', 1, 1) as part1,
       regexp_substr(col, '[^/\+]+', 1, 2) as part2,
       regexp_substr(col, '[^/\+]+', 1, 3) as part3
from t;
```